# как сделать контент NavBar белого цвета?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти вкладки белого цвета
при наведение курсора тоже белые и появляется подчеркивание снизу, но при нажатие
на вкладку **Pricing** Pricing становится черным,хотя я сделал так что если вкладка активна она должна быть белой и так которая не активна тоже белой

css :

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

html :

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark bg-colour">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/img-kozak.png" alt="" width="65px"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
</header>
```

в файле html делал так но не думаю что это корректное решение:

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link active" href="#">Pricing</a>
```

вот таким образом работает,но думаю что это не особо правильно

Comment: Я уже сталкивался с такой лабудой - попробуйте .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus-within{ color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}

Answer (score 0):

Класс `active` обычно присваеваеться ссылке, если текущий URL адресс страницы совпадает с адресом меню. Так, что да - последний вариант явно ошибочный. Есть предположение, что по дефолту в вашей теме ссылкам назначено `:focus` состояние, которое и задает цвет. Попробуйте прописать что-то по типу

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```